# I can not install the necessary dependencies for Skype for Fedora 23 x86_64

Tags: linux, skype, kde, fedora-23

I have a HP Envy dv7 with an `uname -a` output of:

```
Linux MercadesBendz 4.4.7-300.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 13 02:52:52
UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lspci` output of:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core
Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06) 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller:
Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics
Controller (rev 06) 00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon
E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06) 00:14.0
USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family
USB xHCI (rev 05) 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation
8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04) 00:1a.0
USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family
USB EHCI #2 (rev 05) 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8
Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset
Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5) 00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel
Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev d5) 00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5) 00:1d.0 USB
controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB
EHCI #1 (rev 05) 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express
LPC Controller (rev 05) 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8
Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
(rev 05) 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset
Family SMBus Controller (rev 05) 01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom
Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01) 02:00.0 Ethernet controller:
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit
Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

Using the script I put together after researching more than one site, I ran into a problem in this part of it:

```
#Installing Skype
echo Installing Skype dependencies
dnf install alsa-lib.i686 fontconfig.i686 freetype.i686 glib2.i686 libSM.i686 libXScrnSaver.i686 libXi.i686 libXrandr.i686 libXrender.i686 libXv.i686 libstdc++.i686 pulseaudio-libs.i686 qt.i686 qt-x11.i686 zlib.i686 qtwebkit.i686
```

I have pasted the output of the command to this link: 
http://paste.fedoraproject.org/360295/77274014

Normally this problem would present a more obvious reason as to why it's happening, and as a result, how to solve it, but I have another laptop slightly older with the same operating system version and CPU architecture and following the same instructions I got no problems with the dependency installs for the Skype program. This is my first time here so forgive me if I am doing something wrong here, as I am learning on my feet. If anyone needs more information of any sorts I will gladly provide it to the best of my abilities, so I would greatly appreciate any help or ideas because I have nothing left.

Comment: Run sudo dnf clean all. Make sure fedora updates repo is enabled, then run sudo dnf update. Your version of these files(64 bit) are out of date and updating the x86_64 versions first should resolve this. After the update try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did as you suggested but I got the same error. :(

Comment: The output had to have changed if the dnf update worked. The conflicts were with 64bit pkgs for which updates were available on fedora repos. Can you post the new output? I have a fedora 23 laptop and I'll see if I can reproduce what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-skype-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel-scientific-linux-sl

Thanks for all your prompt replies, I decided to install fedora 24 and followed the above guide to install Skype and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Normally, it's better to make answers self-contained because external links break.  In this case, though, the guide is extremely long and much of the information is contained in screenshots, so adding the essential information to your answer would be a job, and your answer is more to update the status of the question than to provide an actionable solution.

Comment: The perfect example of breaking external link is what happened to link to paste.fedoraproject.org in your question above.

Comment: The answer remained the same Skype hasn't changed for Linux in years

Comment: Sorry if I caused any confusion that is never my intention

Answer (score 0):

I need to move this from comments to an answer so it fits. We need to figure out what is dependent on those packages that are causing the conflict so that it can be fixed. Please paste the results into another pastebin site and add the link to your question.

I tried installing the packages as you did on my fedora 23 machine and had no issues / conflicts at all. 
I think what is going on here is that you have multiple versions of those conflicting packages installed because another package marked them as required at that version. We can try uninstalling just the older versions and see what they impact there are other ways to query for this, such as dnf repoquery --whatrequires  --alldeps), but its a bit of a pain in the butt, and asking it to remove the package is quick.

**It is harmless as long as you don't reflexively hit 'Y' when asked if you want to continue the removal and you don't add a '-y' flag to the dnf command.**

First, run the following sequence of commands to clear out the metadata and any cached files, check for any errors in the rpm database, and update the dnf metadata. The dnf check command will take a while to run without any indication of progress.

```
sudo dnf clear all
sudo dnf check
sudo dnf makecache
```

If running *dnf check* outputs any errors, stop here and update your question with that output.

The next one will show us what repos you have installed, and if they are enabled or not.

```
dnf repolist all
```

Now we need to make sure the right ones are enabled.
Go through that list that was just output, and make sure that at least the following 2 repos are listed as "enabled". I don't believe any of the packages you are installing are from other repos, but I didn't exhaustively check - but you aren't having a problem getting them. I did confirm that the updates you need are from one of these two:

fedora

updates

If either of those are not enabled, run one or both of the following commands:

sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled fedora
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled updates

Now run the following:

```
dnf update
```

If there is an error, or nothing updates, please post that info.

The packages we are looking at with multiple versions, which is indicated by the version formatting like pkgname-epoch:version.fc23.arch. If multiple versions are not installed, the epoch is not output by dnf.

```
libpng-2:1.6.17-2.fc23.x86_64
openssl-libs-1:1.0.2d-2.fc23.x86_64
```

Lets see if they are in fact duplicated:

```
dnf repoquery --duplicated
```

Check the list that is output by that call against the list of problem packages, if there are any matches, try to uninstall the older version(s) of the duplicates. You will get a chance to review what will get uninstalled as a result of making this call, so if there are packages you aren't sure of or there are hundreds or thousands listed, click no. If it is a reasonably small number of packages, it will be fine to remove them - you can reinstall if needed.
I would expect only the two packages above will get fixed by this:

```
dnf remove $(dnf repoquery --duplicated --latest-limit -1 -q)
```

Either click yes to remove when prompted by dnf, or post the output and people can help you decide if it's ok to remove them.

The other problem packages that need to be updated are:

```
libgpg-error-1.20-1.fc23.x86_64
alsa-lib-1.0.29-2.fc23.x86_64
pcre-8.37-4.fc23.x86_64
elfutils-libelf-0.163-4.fc23.x86_64
krb5-libs-1.13.2-11.fc23.x86_64
glib2-2.46.1-2.fc23.x86_64
```

For these we need to get info on them. It's possible that are duplicates and were addressed in the earlier step, but the Epoch wasn't indicated for whatever reason. They are all out of date and should be at higher revs, but for some reason you've stated that they are not being updated when calling dnf update.

on each package from the list run this command (I'll just provide an example for the first one):

```
dnf info all libgpg-error
```

This next command might provide a huge list, if so, it probably can't be removed painlessly. If it is an empty list or just a couple items, you can try removing it.

```
dnf repoquery --whatrequires libgpg-error --alldeps
```

Let me know how it goes. These package managers (dnf,yum, apt-get etc) primary job is to avoid these sorts of circular dependency train wrecks, and they are generally pretty good at it these days. Except apparently for you.

What I can tell you is that this issue is not present by default in a fedora 23 install - I had no issues installing those packages. So it was something that was installed at some point, at around the time that those packages were at that version. The --whatrequires information will show you what that program was, if it was a single program and you see it in common with all the problem packages. If you find it, try removing it.